# What is the replacement for IProvider.LoginAsync of Windows Community Toolkit 7.0.0

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I have finally updated CommunityToolkit from 7.0 to 7.1.
[image]

to:

[image]

The OneDrive login code used to be like this:

```
IProvider provider = ProviderManager.Instance.GlobalProvider;
if (provider == null)
{
    //Unable to initialize OneDrive connection;
}
else
{
    if (provider.State == ProviderState.SignedOut)
    {
        await provider.LoginAsync();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, LoginAsync() is no longer available:
[image]

What is the replacement for this method in CommunityToolkit 7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio object browser for `CommunityToolkit.Authentication` shows that `IProvider` contains the method `SignInAsync()`.